# Python : How to "merge" two class

Tags: python, class, merge

I want to add some attributes and methods into various class. The methods and attributes that I have to add are the same but not the class to assign them, so I want to construct a class who assign new methods and attributes for a class given in argument. 
I try this but it's not working:
(I know that is a very wrong way to try to assign something to self, it's just to show what I want to do)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'

    def getattA(self):
        return self.a

class B:
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        self = parent

        # This is working :
        print self.getattA()

    def getattB(self):
        return self.getattA()

insta = A()
instb = B(insta)

# This is not working :
print instb.getattB()
```

The result is :

```
a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents and settings\Bureau\merge.py", line 22, in <module>
    print instb.getattB()
  File "D:\Documents and settings\Bureau\merge.py", line 16, in getattB
    return self.getattA()
AttributeError: B instance has no attribute 'getattA'
```

And I expected to got 'a' for the call of instb.gettattB()

To resume I want to inherit class B from class A giving class A in argument of class B because my class B will be a subclass of various class, not always A.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, could you provide a full example with the expected result? Use `class A(object)` and `class B(object)`, though, at least if you plan to support Python 2.X.

Comment: #this is not working - how is it not working?

Comment: Please post the output that you get when you run the code.

Comment: In [5]: dir(instb)
Out[5]: [`__doc__`, `__init__`, `__module__`, 'getattB']
there is no getatt method with instb object, if you want it you should inherit class B from class A

Comment: self is only accessible in the `__init__` method. You would have to use `self.self = parent` and do `self.self.getatt()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Best answer is in the comments, it was useful for me so I decided to show it in an answer (thank to sr2222):
The way to dynamicaly declare inherance in Python is the type() built-in function.
For my example :

```
class A(object) :
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.a = 'a'
        self.args = args

    def getattA(self):
        return self.a, self.args

class B(object) :
    b = 'b' 
    def __init__(self, args) :
        self.b_init = args

    def getattB(self):
        return self.b

C = type('C', (A,B), dict(c='c'))

instc = C('args')

print 'attributes :', instc.a,  instc.args, instc.b, instc.c
print 'methodes :', instc.getattA(), instc.getattB()

print instc.b_init
```

The code return :

```
attributes : a args b c
methodes : ('a', 'args') b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents and settings\Bureau\merge2.py", line 24, in <module>
    print instc.b_init
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'b_init'
```

My class C inerhite attributes and methods of class A and class B and we add c attribute. With the instanciation of C (instc = C('args')) The **init** for A is call but not for B.

Very useful for me because I have to add some attributes and methodes (the same) on different class.

Comment: I ran into this problem as well, and this is very useful.  For my case, I had different "combinable" subclasses of a parent class.  The addition of specific subclasses became methods of the parent class.

Answer (score 7):

I was having trouble with calling different constructors, using `super` doesn't necessarily make sense in a case like this, I opted to inherit and call each constructor on the current object manually:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, foonum):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        self.foonum = foonum


class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, barnum):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.barnum = barnum

class DiamondProblem(Foo, Bar):
    # Arg order don't matter, since we call the `__init__`'s ourself.
    def __init__(self, barnum, mynum, foonum):
        Foo.__init__(self, foonum)
        Bar.__init__(self, barnum)

        self.mynum = mynum
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but there's an 'TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)' error.
So I annotated 'super(Bar, self).__init__(self)' and ran it again, and it ran well. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'

    def getatt(self):
        return self.a

class B:
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        self.parent = parent

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.parent, attr)

    def getattB(self):
        return self.parent.getatt()

insta = A()
instb = B(insta)

print instb.getattB()
print instb.getatt()
```

But method in class A can not access attr in class B.

Another way:

```
import functools
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'

    def getatt(self):
        return self.a

class B:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        for attr, val in parent.__dict__.iteritems():
            if attr.startswith("__"): continue
            self.__dict__[attr] = val
        for attr, val in parent.__class__.__dict__.iteritems():
            if attr.startswith("__"): continue
            if not callable(val): continue
            self.__dict__[attr] = functools.partial(val, self)

    def getattB(self):
        return self.getatt()

insta = A()
instb = B(insta)

print instb.__dict__
print instb.getattB()
print instb.getatt()
```

Slow with **init** but call fast.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the only way to do what I want. I will assign attribute and method to B with class A. Like (in class B) self.a = self.parent.a and def getatt(self): return self.parent.getatt() I'm looking for a faster way but... Thanks

Comment: This just basically re-implements a new syntax for dynamic inheritance, where Python gives you one to start with.  `insta = A()` `instb = type('B', (A,), {})`.  Just declare a static method on class B that takes an arbitrary length tuple of other classes and returns type([new class name], [tuple of classes including B], [members you want to add at run time]).

Comment: @sr2222, Great, I try `instb = type("", (object, B, insta.__class__), insta.__dict__)()` can do the same thing work better.

Comment: Realy good. I can merge my two class with C = type('C', (A,B), {}). And I have methodes and attributes of A and B in C. (only A is initialize)

Comment: @showns I'm not sure how safe using an empty string for your class name is... also, explicit inheritance of object is unnecessary if you just use new style classes to begin with and have A and B inherit from object themselves.  You should really be using new style classes anyway... and insta.__dict__ is entirely superfluous too, as that's the whole point of subclassing in the first place...

Comment: @sr2222, Yes if A and B is new style classes that will be error. insta.__dict__ can import attr from insta, if doesn't need import,  `def make(base, parent):
 class New(base, parent):
  pass
 return New` work too.

Answer (score 2):

I guess i have a easier method

```py
class fruit1:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "apple"
    self.color = "blue"

class fruit2:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "banana"
    self.size = 100

def merge(ob1, ob2):
    ob1.__dict__.update(ob2.__dict__)
    return ob1

f1 = fruit1()
f2 = fruit2()

fruit = merge(f1, f2)
print("name:",fruit.name," color:",fruit.color, " size:",fruit.size)
#output: name: banana  color: blue  size: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Since B is not a subclass of A, there is no path in B to getatt() in A

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you are trying to do, but the code below is giving my the output I think you are expecting.  notice:

1. a is initialized outside the constructor in A
2. B is declared as a subclass of A

Code:

```
class A:
    a='' #Initialize a

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'

    def getatt(self):
        return self.a

class B(A):  #Declare B as subclass
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        self = parent

        print self.getatt()

    def getattB(self):
        return self.getatt()

insta = A()
instb = B(insta)

print instb.getattB()
```

Comment: Yes, it's what I want to do but the parent of B not always the class A And I would not create a subclass for every class.

Comment: Assigning a value to `self` is just wrong, and it does not escape the function body scope...

Comment: I don't think it's possible to dynamically set a parent class.  The parent has to be declared in order for the compiler to find the superclass's attributes.  If `B` is not declared a subclass of `A`, you won't be able to access `a`

Comment: @Po'Lazarus I know this, but I wanted to give him a "solution" to his problem.  I don't know why he's doing what he's doing, so I didn't want to tell him that what he is doing is wrong, just give him a way to get the output he wants.

Comment: You can dynamically declare inheritance in Python.  If you have a builder function that receives one or more type arguments, you can pass them in to type() and create a new type subclassed from those types at run time.

Comment: Well, for basic use cases, `type()` is the builder function... `Fooish = type('Fooish', (Foo,), {})` will give you a variable named Fooish that is a handle for a new object of type Fooish that derives from Foo and has no additional custom members.

Answer (score 0):

Helper function below conducts the merge of the dataclass instances, the attributes orders is derived from `*args` order:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    foo: str
    bar: str


def merge_dataclasses(*args):
    if len({e.__class__.__name__ for e in args}) > 1:
        raise NotImplementedError('Merge of non-homogeneous entries no allowed.')
    data = {}
    for entry in args[::-1]:
        data.update(vars(entry))
    return entry.__class__(**data)

print(merge_dataclasses(A(foo='f', bar='bar'), A(foo='b_foo', bar='b_bar')))
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to merge two or more classes is through the tool set [dyndesign](https://pypi.org/project/dyndesign/):

```
from dyndesign import mergeclasses

class Base:
    def __init__(self, init_value):
        self.param = init_value

    def m1(self):
        print(f"Method `m1` of class `Base`, and {self.param=}")

    def m2(self):
        print(f"Method `m2` of class `Base`")

class Ext:
    def m1(self):
        print(f"Method `m1` of class `Ext`, and {self.param=}")

MergedClass = mergeclasses(Base, Ext)
merged_instance = MergedClass("INITIAL VALUE")

merged_instance.m1()
# Method `m1` of class `Ext`, and self.param='INITIAL VALUE'

merged_instance.m2()
# Method `m2` of class `Base`
```

Answer (score 0):

Emphasizing [ThorSummoner's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695680/thorsummoner)'s answer and [Hong's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11403603/hong%EC%8A%B9%EC%9B%90) comment; this method appears to be cleaner than the excepted answer.  Notice Hong's use of super().**init**(self) in all but the last object added to the merge class.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, foonum):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(self)
        self.foonum = foonum


class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, barnum):
        super(Bar, self).__init__(self)
        self.barnum = barnum


class Oops(object):
    def __init__(self, oopsnum):
        super(Oops, self).__init__()
        self.oopsnum = oopsnum


class DiamondProblem(Foo, Bar, Oops):
    def __init__(self, mynum, foonum, barnum, oopsnum):
        Foo.__init__(self, foonum)
        Bar.__init__(self, barnum)
        Oops.__init__(self, oopsnum)

        self.mynum = mynum


def main():
    dia = DiamondProblem(1, 10, 20, 30)
    print(f"mynum: {dia.mynum}")
    print(f"foonum: {dia.foonum}")
    print(f"barnum: {dia.barnum}")
    print(f"oopsnum: {dia.oopsnum}")
```