# Python imshow: how to get merge two <class 'matplotlib.image.AxesImage'> into one?

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, merge, imshow

I want my function to return a single `< class 'matplotlib.image.AxesImage' >` type of object after displaying two `< class 'matplotlib.image.AxesImage' >` with `imshow`:

```
def merge_class(array1,array2):
    plt.imshow(array1)
    plt.imshow(array2)
    return ?
```

How do I do that ?

I heard that I could save the entire figure and then call the file in my programm but I want to avoid that.

I also saw that I could merge these objects but I don't understand what they do: [Python : How to "merge" two class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667818/python-how-to-merge-two-class)

**EDIT 1:** I want to know that because I am making an animation and for one frame there are two layers: a picture and above an array.

```
movie.append([plt.imshow(merge_class(array1,array2), animated=True, interpolation='none', origin='lower')])
```

The object in the movie list needs to be a `< class 'matplotlib.image.AxesImage' >` and if I only return `plt.show()` in my function it will return a `None`.

**EDIT 2:** I am simulating a forest fire.

In the array `forest` and `forest_fire`:

- no tree = 0.0
- non-burning tree = 1.0
- burning tree = 2.0

The `set_on_fire` function returns a new forest, in which the tree at the coordinates (i,j) is on fire.

The `check_fire` function returns True if at least one non-burning tree can burn.

The `spreading_fire` function returns a new forest, in which the trees that can burn are on fire.

Here is part of the code:

```
# maido is the name of a mountain and a forest

def img_maido(img_file,forest):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots()

    # 1) Opening the picture as an array
    img_array = plt.imread(img_file)
    img = np.copy(img_array[::-1,:,:]) # I flip it because it is upside down

    # 2) Hiding all the 'no tree' values (0.0)
    forest = np.ma.masked_where(forest == 0.0, forest) # The array is transparent at each one of the 'no tree' values position (0.0)

    # 3) The 'non-burning tree' values (1.0) are green and the 'burning tree' values (2.0) are red
    cmap = ListedColormap(['green','red'], 'indexed')

    # 4) Displaying the array 'img' of the mountain and the array 'forest' of the forest above it
    plt.imshow(forest,zorder=1, cmap=cmap, origin='lower')
    plt.imshow(img,zorder=0, origin='lower')

    return ? # Here is my issue


def fire_animation(img_file,forest,i,j,wind):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    movie = []    

    # 1) Initialization
    forest_fire = set_on_fire(forest,i,j) # I put a 'burning tree' value (2.0) in the array 'forest' at the coordinates (i,j)
    movie.append([plt.imshow(img_maido(img_file,forest_fire), animated=True, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none', origin='lower')])
    plt.draw()

    # 2) Spread of fire
    while check_fire(foret,wind):
        forest_fire = spreading_fire(forest_fire,wind)
        movie.append([plt.imshow(img_maido(img_file,forest_fire), animated=True, interpolation='none', origin='lower')])
        plt.draw()

    # 3) Animation
    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, movie, interval=100, blit=True, repeat_delay=100)

    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Merging two `AxesImage`s isn't possible. However there also is not need to do that. If you tell us why you want that and what you expect the result to look like there will surely be a solution.

Comment: Making a movie should not be a problem even with lots of artists. Can you show how you make the movie?. Best show a [MCVE] that is working for one image, and fails for two images with comments in the code where you  have problems.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope my English is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no reason to use an array to append the artists in this case. You can simply use a function that changes the array for each iteration.

In the example below, we create a figure and an axes and plot the two arrays to them. Each image is saved in a variable.

We then create an animation which repeatedly calls a function `burn`. Inside this function we manipulate one of the arrays and set new data to one of the images, leaving the other untouched. The changed image is then the return value of this function. Note, the `,` after the return value. This comma makes the return value a sequence, which means, that we could also change both images and return both if we wanted to. However, this is not necessary, since the background does not change in our case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,40)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)

static_array = (X/40.)**2+(Y/30.)**2 

dynamic_array = np.floor(np.random.random(X.shape)*1.1)
masked_dynamic_array = np.ma.masked_where(dynamic_array <=0.7 , dynamic_array)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

static_image =  ax.imshow(static_array, cmap="terrain")
dynamic_image = ax.imshow(dynamic_array, cmap="magma")

def burn(i):
    rand = (np.random.random(X.shape)-0.3)
    new = dynamic_array + 0.1*rand
    dynamic_array[:,:] = new/new.max()
    masked_dynamic_array = np.ma.masked_where(dynamic_array <=0.7 , dynamic_array)
    dynamic_image.set_data(masked_dynamic_array)
    return dynamic_image,

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, burn, interval=100, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If the number of iterations is unknown, you can first run the simulation, store the resulting arrays in a list. Once that's finished, use the length of this list as the number of frames to animate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,40)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)

static_array = (X/40.)**2+(Y/30.)**2 
dynamic_array = np.floor(np.random.random(X.shape)*1.1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))


static_image =  ax.imshow(static_array, cmap="terrain")
dynamic_image = ax.imshow(dynamic_array, cmap="magma", vmin=0., vmax=4.)

ims = []
while dynamic_array.mean() < 1.5:
    rand = (np.random.random(X.shape)-0.4)
    new = dynamic_array + 0.085*rand
    new[new > 4] = 4.
    dynamic_array[:,:] = new
    masked_dynamic_array = np.ma.masked_where(dynamic_array <=0.7 , dynamic_array)
    ims.append(masked_dynamic_array)

def burn(i):
    dynamic_image.set_data(ims[i])
    return dynamic_image,

plt.tight_layout()    
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, burn, frames=len(ims), interval=100, blit=True)
ani.save(__file__+'.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: But if I want to save the animation, will the background still be visible in the GIF or MP4 file ?

Comment: Sure, why not? Simply use something like `ani.save(__file__+'.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=10)` But don't forget to specify the number of frames in the call to FuncAnimation, e.g. `frames=30`. Otherwise the file will get infinitely large.

Comment: Allright thank you I will try it tomorrow because I need some sleep (10h30 pm here ;) ) and I will show you what I get.

Comment: There is another issue: I don't know the number of frame that I have each time I run the program because the program is suppose to stop when `check_fire` returns `False` and that's why I used `ArtistAnimation` instead of `FuncAnimation` in the first place.

Comment: It seems to work for me thank you but can you tell me what do `set_data` and `tight_layout` do ?

Comment: `set_data` sets the array to the `Image`. So instead of creating a lot of new `Image` instances, you just change the data inside. (When putting a new picture on the wall, you wouldn't buy a new frame and throw the old one away, you'd just reuse the old one for the new picture.) [`tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) is not really necessary here actually; it makes the axes fit into the canvas more tightly, reducing the space around it or prevent the axis labels from disappearing out of the canvas.