# Python combine two classes

Tags: python, class

I need implement method (i think it's method **add**) responsible for adding a Сar with an AirPlane.
i need to get Class AirCar whose length and weight will be equal to the average between the attributes of the Car and the AirPlane.
so my code below

```
class Car:
        average_speed = 60
        average_length = 5
        cars = []
    
        def __init__(self, model, speed=average_speed, length=average_length):
            self.model = model
            self.speed = speed
            self.length = length
    
    
    class AirPlane(Car):
        average_speed = 300
        average_length = 10
        AirPlane = []
    
        def magic(self):
            super(Car, self).__init__()
    
    
    class AirCar(Car, AirPlane):
        def __add__(self, other):
            if self.cars:
                self.average_speed = sum([car.speed for car in self.cars]) / len(self.cars)
                self.average_length = sum([AirPlane.length for AirPlane in self.AirPlane]) / len(self.AirPlane)
                self.Aircar.append(self)
    
Tesla = Car("Tesla", speed=300, length=4)
Boing = AirPlane('Boing', speed=600, length=20)
```

Output
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Car, AirPlane

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667818/python-how-to-merge-two-class this might be useful

Comment: Can you please *edit* your question to include 1) The output of your code 2) the exact expected output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, hope we can help.  To add to the chorus though, please also edit your code to make sure it's formatted correctly.  With Python in particular it's very important to get indentation correct, so please make sure the code in your question is exactly the same as what you're looking at in your editor; otherwise it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @deadshot need to combine Car + Airplane and get AirCar - will be equal to the average between the attributes of the Car and the Airplane

Comment: @mousetail output TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Car, AirPlane

Comment: 1. `AirPlane` is already combined with `Car` by inheriting from it. You can't combine them again with another class. 2. `__add__` is supposed to return a new object, not modify `self`. It's unclear whether you really need an `__add__` method or if you're trying to do something completely different.

Comment: @luther, i want to combine Car with Airplane and get AirCar ( will be equal to the average between the attributes of the Car and the Airplane)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be along the lines of what you're trying to do but I'm not sure:

```py
>>> class Vehicle:
...     average_speed = None
...     average_length = None
...     def __init__(self, model, speed=None, length=None):
...         self.model = model
...         self.speed = speed if speed is not None else self.average_speed
...         self.length = length if length is not None else self.average_length
... 
... 
>>> class Car(Vehicle):
...     average_speed = 60
...     average_length = 5
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         if isinstance(other, Plane):
...             return CarPlane(self.model + other.model,
...                             speed=(self.speed + other.speed) / 2,
...                             length=(self.length + other.length) / 2)
...         return NotImplemented
...
...     __radd__ = __add__
... 
>>> class Plane(Vehicle):
...     average_speed = 300
...     average_length = 10
... 
>>> class CarPlane(Car, Plane):
...     average_speed = (Car.average_speed + Plane.average_speed) / 2
...     average_length = (Car.average_length + Plane.average_length) / 2
>>> car = Car('Tesla')
>>> plane = Plane('Boeing')
>>> carplane = car + plane
>>> carplane
<__main__.CarPlane object at 0x7f5744c8a850>
>>> carplane.model, carplane.speed, carplane.length
('TeslaBoeing', 180.0, 7.5)
```

**Update:** If you want to combine any kind of vehicle with any other kind of vehicle you could go further and generate the combined classes on the fly:

```py
>>> class Vehicle:
...     average_speed = None
...     average_length = None
...     _compound_vehicle_classes = {}
... 
...     def __init__(self, model, speed=None, length=None):
...         self.model = model
...         self.speed = speed if speed is not None else self.average_speed
...         self.length = length if length is not None else self.average_length
...
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(model={self.model!r}, speed={self.speed}, length={self.length})'
... 
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         if not isinstance(other, Vehicle):
...             return NotImplemented
...         cls_a = self.__class__
...         cls_b = other.__class__
...         if (cls_a is cls_b):
...             cls = cls_a
...         elif False:
...             # exercise to reader: what if cls_a or cls_b is already
...             # a compound vehicle class?  You could still resolve this
...             # by checking the __mro__ of each class, for example; you
...             # could also use this to combine a third or even fourth
...             # type of vehicle into some kind of Voltron ^_~
...             pass
...         else:
...             key = (cls_a, cls_b)
...             if key in self._compound_vehicle_classes:
...                 cls = self._compound_vehicle_classes[key]
...             else:
...                 cls = type(cls_a.__name__ + cls_b.__name__,
...                            (cls_a, cls_b),
...                            {'average_length': (cls_a.average_length + cls_b.average_length) / 2,
...                             'average_speed': (cls_a.average_speed + cls_b.average_speed) / 2})
...                 self._compound_vehicle_classes[key] = cls
...         return cls(self.model + other.model, speed=(self.speed + other.speed) / 2,
...                    length=(self.length + other.length) / 2)
... 
>>> class Car(Vehicle):
...     average_speed = 60
...     average_length = 5
... 
>>> class Plane(Vehicle):
...     average_speed = 300
...     average_length = 10
... 
>>> 
>>> class Boat(Vehicle):
...     average_speed = 20
...     average_length = 100
... 
>>> car = Car('Tesla')
>>> plane = Plane('Boeing')
>>> boat = Boat('Evergreen')
>>> carplane = car + plane
>>> carplane
CarPlane(model='TeslaBoeing', speed=180.0, length=7.5)
>>> planecar = plane + car
>>> planecar
PlaneCar(model='BoeingTesla', speed=180.0, length=7.5)
>>> car + boat
CarBoat(model='TeslaEvergreen', speed=40.0, length=52.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but that's not quite right, you count the average speed from the class, but if you add data, they will not be counted.
I don't quite understand how to do it

Comment: `car = Car("Tesla", speed=100, length=4)
plane = Plane('Boeing', speed=100, length=8)
carplane = car + plane
print(carplane.average_speed)
print(carplane.average_length)`

Comment: @Heyit'sSerge: If you add two vehicles with different models together, what should the model of the new vehicle be? Also, I wonder if you're conflating addition with combining in place. Those are two very different things.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want here. In your (non-functioning) code you made `average_speed` a class attribute, at least in some cases, which you used as the default speed of a vehicle. I would have called it `default_speed` but it could also be seen as an "average speed" of a car so whatever. When you add a Car and a Plane the new CarPlane has a `speed` which is the average of the `car.speed` and `plane.speed`. I don't know what other value you would want it to have.